# credentialSecret option and _cred.json file

Tags: security, encryption, node-red

Without making any changes to `settings.js` file, I can see two JSON documents in `.node_red` folder - one for the flows and other for credentials. For example, `flows_ip-xxx-xxx-xx-xx_cred.json` and `flows_ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.json`. Then, there is a field as `credentialSecret` in the `settings.js` file.

On a fresh Node-RED installation, suppose, I manually copied `flows_ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.json` **only**, from an earlier installation, followed by a restart. I will copy into a `different_name.json` that is also mentioned for the `flowFile` property. Then, are the credentials still copied over but encrypted with a (different) auto-generated password? In which case, if I defined a common value for `credentialSecret` option in `settings.js` for both installations, the nodes would get correct credentials in the new installation?

I should probably be using the projects option; but, until then, I want to figure out the credentials behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not set a `credentialSecret` in `settings.js` then Node-RED will create a key the first time it starts and store it in the hidden file called `.config.runtime.json` in the user directory.

This key will be used to encrypt the `flows_creds.json` to protect the credentials file.

If you need to move a flow to a new machine then you can copy the `_credentialSecret` value from  `.config.runtime.json` to the `credentialSecret` in the new `settings.js` to allow it to decrypt the existing credentials file.

If you are starting from scratch then you can choose to define your own `credentialSecret` in the `settings.js` on both machines to allow them to decrypt a common `flow_creds.json` file.

And yes the new project feature makes this a lot easier.